# c# 2D drawing for image does not draw image

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

why using this snippet does not draw an image on the screen? there are other commands to draw before this line they work fine. for example, there some rectangle and fill shape command that works.

```
Graphics imgGB = e.Graphics;
imgGB.DrawImage(
    Properties.Resources.logo,
    new Rectangle(
        new Point(DoorGlassFill.Left, DoorPrimeter.Bottom + Drawing_HandleHeight),
    new Size(200,200)));
```

the whole method is:

```
//draw door
Graphics DoorGP = e.Graphics;
Rectangle DoorFrame = new Rectangle(new Point(DoorPrimeter.Left + Drawing_LeftDis + Drawing_Off, DoorPrimeter.Top + TopDistance + (2*Drawing_Off)+Drawing_TopBlockHeight), new Size(Drawing_DoorWidth,DoorPrimeter.Height-TopDistance-Drawing_TopBlockHeight-(2*Drawing_Off)));
DoorGP.DrawRectangle(pen, DoorFrame);
Rectangle GP113 = new Rectangle(new Point(DoorFrame.Left+Drawing_GP113,DoorFrame.Top+Drawing_GP113), new Size(DoorFrame.Width-(2*Drawing_GP113),DoorFrame.Height-Drawing_GP113));
DoorGP.DrawRectangle(pen, GP113);
Rectangle DoorGlass = new Rectangle(new Point(GP113.Left+Drawing_GP119,GP113.Top+Drawing_GP119), new Size(GP113.Width-(2*Drawing_GP119),GP113.Height-Drawing_GP119));
Graphics GlassFillGP = e.Graphics;
Rectangle DoorGlassFill = new Rectangle(new Point(GP113.Left + Drawing_GP119, GP113.Top + Drawing_GP119), new Size(GP113.Width - (2 * Drawing_GP119), GP113.Height - (2 * Drawing_GP119)));
GlassFillGP.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(DoorGlassFill, Color.AliceBlue, Color.LightSkyBlue, 45f), DoorGlassFill);
DoorGP.DrawRectangle(pen, DoorGlass);
Graphics imgGB = e.Graphics;
imgGB.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.logo__sajiran1,new Rectangle(new Point(DoorGlassFill.Left, DoorPrimeter.Bottom + Drawing_HandleHeight),new Size(200,200)));
```

tried this too:

```
//draw door
                    Graphics DoorGP = e.Graphics;
                    Rectangle DoorFrame = new Rectangle(new Point(DoorPrimeter.Left + Drawing_LeftDis + Drawing_Off, DoorPrimeter.Top + TopDistance + (2*Drawing_Off)+Drawing_TopBlockHeight), new Size(Drawing_DoorWidth,DoorPrimeter.Height-TopDistance-Drawing_TopBlockHeight-(2*Drawing_Off)));
                    DoorGP.DrawRectangle(pen, DoorFrame);
                    Rectangle GP113 = new Rectangle(new Point(DoorFrame.Left+Drawing_GP113,DoorFrame.Top+Drawing_GP113), new Size(DoorFrame.Width-(2*Drawing_GP113),DoorFrame.Height-Drawing_GP113));
                    DoorGP.DrawRectangle(pen, GP113);
                    Rectangle DoorGlass = new Rectangle(new Point(GP113.Left+Drawing_GP119,GP113.Top+Drawing_GP119), new Size(GP113.Width-(2*Drawing_GP119),GP113.Height-Drawing_GP119));
                    Graphics GlassFillGP = e.Graphics;
                    Rectangle DoorGlassFill = new Rectangle(new Point(GP113.Left + Drawing_GP119, GP113.Top + Drawing_GP119), new Size(GP113.Width - (2 * Drawing_GP119), GP113.Height - (2 * Drawing_GP119)));
                    GlassFillGP.FillRectangle(new LinearGradientBrush(DoorGlassFill, Color.AliceBlue, Color.LightSkyBlue, 45f), DoorGlassFill);
                    DoorGP.DrawRectangle(pen, DoorGlass);
                    Bitmap img = Properties.Resources.Handle_Meroni;
                    Graphics imgGB = e.Graphics;
                    img.SetResolution(imgGB.DpiX, imgGB.DpiY);
                    imgGB.DrawImage(img,new Rectangle(new Point(DoorGlassFill.Left, DoorPrimeter.Bottom + Drawing_HandleHeight),new Size(200,200)));
```

Comment: Where does e.Graphics come from? A Paint event? What does Properties.Resources.logo look like? How large is it?  (200x200)?  dpi?

Comment: @TaW e.Graphics come from a paint event, whole code is in a paint event scope. propertiese.Resources.Logo is a PNG file and is 316x316 px

Comment: OK. You draw only 200x200 of the 316x316, but unless it is all at the bottom-right you should still see something. (To draw the full image you sould use the overload with two rectangles.) Provided the location is in scope. Use the debugger to test that! I wonder why you keep re-assigning the Graphics object to 3 different variables. It still is the same object, so this seems to make no senses. Nor any difference..

Comment: @TaW , the problem is cannot see anything, if i could i can modify it, i had a problem with "fillrectangle" in graphics when i used that in the same object as that one that i used to draw lines, lines and rectangles disappeared from the screen, and only fill was shown.

Comment: There is only one Graphics object, just a bunch of redundant references. What is the dpi of the image? (it is honored!) - Did you look into the rectangle coordinates? - Can you comment out the other lines and test what happens? Also using the [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you better control; recommended!

Comment: @TaW yes, coordinates were correct, with same code when i commented the fillshape line, previous drawn lines and rectangles were disappeared. this image's dpi is 300,

Comment: If you draw an 300dpi image onto a ~96dpi screen it will not work as expected. Pull it out of the resources and change the dpi to be the same as Graphics' dpi! Can you post the logo image?

Comment: @TaW is this possible to change its dpi ain runtime according to screen dpi? and how can i get screen dpi programmatically and normally?

Comment: `img.SetResolution(G.DpiX, G.DpiY);` with G being the Graphics object. As it is meant to draw on the screen it has its resolution.

Comment: @TaW not shown again, question updated, see the last section!

Comment: I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Sure. Imo it is time for a sanity check: Try to draw the same image to a test control..

Comment: @TaW yes, i am on it